# Echart.js charts isn't showing tooltip

Tags: javascript, charts

I am using Echart.js library.

var echartLine = echarts.init(document.getElementById('myChart'), theme);

In echart option I add :

```
tooltip: {
                    show: true,
                    showContent: true,
                    alwaysShowContent: true,
                    triggerOn: 'mousemove',
                    trigger: 'axis',
                    axisPointer:
                        {
                            label: {
                                show: true,
                            }
                        }

                },
```

Tooltip don't appear. Image is bellow. 
[image]

Comment: Its because its in canvas element. I try to add in div but its doesn't render chart. Can anyone now why?

Answer (score 2):

Change the option trigger: 'axis' to trigger: 'item' and it should work like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

for visitors: do not use `canvas` as container, `init` your echarts with `div` instead, tooltips should show then.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was that I put the "tooltip" object into the "series" object. Don't be like me. Put these objects near.

Answer (score 0):

In my case work when i add the option axisPointer.axis to 'x', leaving like this:

```
tooltip: {
    trigger: "axis",
    axisPointer: {
      type: "shadow",
      axis: "x"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My tool tip in Eachart was not showing. The mistake was using allow copy extension of Google Chrome, so please check that is active or not, please disable the extension the total tip will shows in charts.